# Matlab calculating radians from -pi to pi instead of 0 to 2pi

Tags: matlab, mapping, angle, complex-numbers, logarithm

I am working on a problem where the pressure profile is supposed to be smooth. For this the angle should be from `0` to `2pi`. But when I take the logarithm of certain complex numbers, MATLAB maps the angle to the `pi` to negative `pi` range (clockwise direction).

For example :

```
var_z = [20.0 + 0.6i,  20.0 - 0.6i];
za2 = -2.5000 + 0.5000i;
A = log (-(var_z-za2))
```

yields `A = [3.11 - 3.13i, 3.11 + 3.091i]`, but if the angle was only in the counterclockwise direction (i.e. `[0, 2pi]`) we'd get `[3.11 + 3.14i,  3.11 + 3.09i]` instead.

The latter result makes more sense in my situation as it prevents the pressure profiles from rapidly jumping up. Is there any way to force MATLAB to use `0` to `2pi` for the radians?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`log`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/log.html), for complex numbers the performed computation is this:

```
log(abs(z)) + 1i*angle(z)
```

It appears we can just "redefine" this slightly by adding a 2π-modulus, then explicitly applying the above set of operations instead of the `log` function:

```
log(abs(z)) + 1i*mod(angle(z),2*pi)
```

Thus if we define a function handle and compare the results:

```
l = @(z)log(abs(z)) + 1i*mod(angle(z),2*pi);
```

```
>> log(-([20.0 + 0.6i,  20.0 - 0.6i]-(-2.5000 + 0.5000i)))

ans =

   3.1135 - 3.1371i   3.1147 + 3.0927i

>> l(-([20.0 + 0.6i,  20.0 - 0.6i]-(-2.5000 + 0.5000i)))

ans =

   3.1135 + 3.1460i   3.1147 + 3.0927i
```

... we see that the desired result is achieved.

Answer (score -1):

A formula to calculate an angle from 0 to 2pi:

```
f(x,y)=pi()-pi()/2*(1+sign(x))*(1-sign(y^2))-pi()/4*(2+sign(x))*sign(y)
       -sign(x*y)*atan((abs(x)-abs(y))/(abs(x)+abs(y)))
```